# User input ends after inputting float

Tags: c++, getline

I am trying to get a C++ program to output user inputs into an empty file. However, when after inputting a float, the program ends the current session of input by calling up the next session. Below is the code of the function for the user inputs.

```
vector<Item> insertProducts()
{  
    vector<Item> products;

    string name;
    string code;
    float price;
    string unit;

    bool repeat = true;

    while(repeat) // program will keep asking for another round of input after one session ends
    {
        cout << "Enter product description: ";
        getline(cin, name);

        if(name.compare("#") != 0) // program stop asking for input if # is entered
        {
            cout << "Enter product code: ";
            getline(cin, code);
            cout << "Enter product unit price: ";
            cin >> price;
            cout << "Enter product unit phrase: ";
            getline(cin, unit);
            cout << "" << endl;

            Item newProduct = Item(code, name, price, unit);
            products.push_back(newProduct);
        }
        else
        {
            repeat = false;
            printCatalog(products);
        } 
    }

    return products;
}
```

Below is the result after inputting a float for price whereby the program skipped input of unit phrase and go right into another round of input.

```
Enter product description: Potato Chips
Enter product code: P3487
Enter product unit price: 1.9
Enter product unit phrase: Enter product description:
```

May I know what causes this problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that after `cin >> price;`, the newline character which the user used to terminate the input of the price is still in the input buffer—it's the next character to be read. The following `std::getline` then reads it and returns an empty line.

The most robust way of clearing such a trailing newline is to tell the stream to ignore everything up to and including the next newline:

```
cin >> price;
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cin.ignore();
```

before calling the getline() function

Alternatively, you can try using

```
cin.clear();
cin.sync();
```

at the beginning of your code

This will flush the input buffer.

Comment: Please explain why this would help rather than just saying what code to write.